# Dynamically update the options of a chart in chartjs using Javascript

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have created a line chart that is able to update its data successfully in chartjs and I am trying to change the option values dynamically as well. More specifically I want to be able to change the scale. I would like to avoid re-creating the chart everytime updates are needed. Is there a way to update the options dynamically such as  :

```
myLiveChart.options.scaleStepWidth = 10;
myLiveChart.update();
```

Note: I have tried the following as well :

```
myLiveChart.scaleStepWidth = 10;
```

Also tried `myLiveChart.render();` instead of update, but nothing seems to really work.

here is a fiddle illustrating the problem: http://jsbin.com/yaxafehixe/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: did you check the chartjs docs? this of any use - http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-update-default-scale-config

Comment: @ Craicerjack :yes i did, but I couldn't find info on specifically want i wanted to do.. which is to update the options, and not the dataset. What i've tried so far (using the render or update function) is based on the docs .

Comment: problem is : i am not sure exactly where to check 

options such as:  scaleOverride, scaleSteps ,scaleStepWidth: , scaleStartValue are not in `scales` section, they are directly under `options` section

Comment: yeah looking at the docs I dont know, it seems the options are added to the chart upon its creation and to update them you need to re-render the chart or re-create it...

Comment: @Craicerjack : that would suck a little. I don't think that's the case though, because in my fiddle I have tried `myLiveChart.options.animation = true;`  and to my surprise it worked... which is weird because any other options i've tried, such as the ones i am trying to change, are not working...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found a solution that works in case anybody googles this. Here is the thing : I was using chartjs version 1, in which the update() function doesn't work in all cases, especially when you are trying to change the options of a chart. Therefore, switching to version 2, allowed me to use update() properly with changing the options such as :

```
myChart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.min = someValue;
```

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate the solution to my problem in case anybody faces the same issue: http://jsbin.com/bamemuliyu/3/edit?html,js,output