# How to change ChartJS font size with javascript?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have an array of charts on the page called `charts`. This is the code I tried to run to make the font change:

```
for(var x in charts){
    charts[x].options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.fontSize = 20;
    charts[x].options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.fontSize = 20;
    charts[x].update();
}
```

I know that I am correctly reaching the `fontSize` attribute because in the console it returns the right font size to me. After I change the fontSize, it returns the correct one. For some reason, however, the actual charts aren't updating. Is the `chart.update` command only made for updating data?

Note: This question is not a duplicate of the other question that exists about dynamically updating charts with JS because the ChartJS version I am using is 2.7.

Comment: Which version of chart.js are you using? This person was using version 1 and had your problem but it seems after updating to version 2, they could update the chart options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38643994/dynamically-update-the-options-of-a-chart-in-chartjs-using-javascript

Comment: @earthling I am using 2.7.0

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48580585/7186739

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In ChartJS version *2.7.0* or later, changing *(dynamically)* the font-size of chart axis' ticks by just setting the `fontSize` property of `ticks` won't actually apply to the chart. It will only add empty spaces for newly set font-size to the axis'.

In order to change the font-size of chart axis' ticks properly *(which would apply to the chart)*, you will need to set `fontSize` property for the **`minor`** object *(under `ticks`)* , like so :

```
for (var x in charts) {
   // set/change the actual font-size
   charts[x].options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.minor.fontSize = 20;
   charts[x].options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.minor.fontSize = 20;

   // set proper spacing for resized font
   charts[x].options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.fontSize = 20;
   charts[x].options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.fontSize = 20;

   // update chart to apply new font-size
   charts[x].update();
}
```

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**

```js
var myChart1 = new Chart(ctx1, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'Profit',
         data: [30, 10, 40, 20, 50],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(61, 208, 239, 0.2)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(61, 208, 239, 0.6)'
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});

var myChart2 = new Chart(ctx2, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'Loss',
         data: [50, 20, 40, 10, 30],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(239, 92, 61, 0.2)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(239, 92, 61, 0.6)'
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});

var charts = [myChart1, myChart2];

function changeFontSize() {
   for (var x in charts) {
      // set/change the font-size
      charts[x].options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.minor.fontSize = 20;
      charts[x].options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.minor.fontSize = 20;

      // set proper spacing for resized font
      charts[x].options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.fontSize = 20;
      charts[x].options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.fontSize = 20;

      // update chart to apply new font-size
      charts[x].update();
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="changeFontSize();">Change Font Size</button>
<canvas id="ctx1"></canvas>
<canvas id="ctx2"></canvas>
```