# how to change object properties by on-click

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am having object like

funnel chart with options

```
var positon={
options:{
sort:"desc";
}
}
```

in that case my chart in reverse position .
But what i need is when i click the button sort must change to "asc" and my chart must be in straight position

i tried the following

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
      console.log("working");
         if (config.options.sort == 'asc') {
       config.options.sort= 'asc';

    } else {
         config.options.sort = 'desc';
        console.log("calling here 2" + config.options.sort);
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi @ uncle dave i had tried the above code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
var positon ={
        options: {
         sort:"desc"
       }
   }

onSortClick() {
  positon.options.sort = positon.options.sort === "desc" ? "asc": "desc"
  return positon.options.sort;
};
```

In your plunker do these changes.

Add a button.

```
  <button id="sort-btn">Sort</button>
```

Add an event listner

```
  document.getElementById("sort-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
      config.options.sort = config.options.sort === "desc" ? "asc" : "desc";
      var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
      window.myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx, config);
      console.log(config.options.sort);
    });
```

Comment: @anurag  i had provided my fiddle can u please check

Comment: did you add the above functionality to the plunker?

Comment: in plunker i did not added but i tried in the local

Comment: I do not know about the graph. But the sort property is changing according to the conditions.

Comment: but i need that to change in the chart bro

Comment: bro can u please update it in my plunker i was little confused

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174150/discussion-between-anuradha-gunasekara-and-pradeep).

Comment: bro the chart being change with mouse-hover also but i dont need it with hover this the last query

Comment: hi@anuradha bro

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple you just have to create an event listener.

```
<input type="button" id="myCheck" onclick="reverse()">

<script>
function reverse() {
    config.options.sort = "asc";        
}
</script>
```

Comment: let me check this Anurag

Comment: For more please check `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38643994/dynamically-update-the-options-of-a-chart-in-chartjs-using-javascript`

Comment: bro it  tried all the ways but it is not working for me

Comment: wait i will provide my fiddle

Comment: bro it is working but it is been changing with mouse over also i dont want that to be done with mouse over

Comment: I think solution is provided by @Anuradha Gunasekara, Just a suggestion: just read documentation of any Library and you can do any thing you want to do with that.